# how to set node attribute value from execute resouce command output

Tags: chef-infra

```
execute 'my_commad' do
  command 'myvar=`curl http://example.com/blah/blah` && echo -n $myvar > /etc/value'
end

node.default[:attribute1] = ::File.read('/etc/value').chomp
```

This will fail, because at the time of convergence the node attributes are checked first and hence it will throw the following error:

> ERROR: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /etc/value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are setting the node attribute at the recipe itself and not in an attribute file, this might work for you. though, in my opinion, there is a better way to do so...

you can use [`ruby_block`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_ruby_block.html) and use ruby code to fetch the value that you need from the url and then assign it to a node attribute. it will be something like:

```
ruby_block 'fetch value' do
  block do
    require 'net/http'
    require 'uri'

    url = 'http://example.com/blah/blah'
    val = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse(url))
    node.default[:attribute1] = val
end
```

just make sure that every read for the `attribute1` node attribute, is taking place after it was assigned. you might need to rearrange the node run-list to make sure that all recipes that depend on this recipe, will be appear in the node run-list after the recipe above was executed.

Comment: Hi @Mr. Thanks for your answer. However, I want to use that node.default[:attribute1] in another resource. Which is the main issue currently for me. I have tried node.run_state[:attribute1] however it doesn't worked for me.

Comment: @maheshs007: i've updated my post. see last paragraph.