# How to run a ruby block in a recipe and pass the result to a template

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

You all helped me the other day with some ruby code to parse a string and modify it ([How to verify that the last character in a string is a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58528289/how-to-verify-that-the-last-character-in-a-string-is-a-number)). Now, the trick is how do I plug that into a chef recipe in order to populate to a template?

The ruby block gives me the result I need, at least when I test in standalone ruby. From searching online, it seemed like one way to do this was with run_state[]. Unfortunately, it does not populate to the template.

Basically, in the recipe, I've got the following block of code:

```
ruby_block "new db home" do
  block do
    if node['oracledb']['oraclehome']['db']['home'].split('/')[-1].include?('dbhome_')
      db_home = node['oracledb']['oraclehome']['db']['home']
      digits = db_home[/\d+$/]
      db_home[/\d+$/] = digits.to_i.next.to_s if digits
    else
      db_home = db_home + "/dbhome_1"
    end
    node.run_state['new_db_home'] = db_home
  end
  not_if { node['oracledb']['oraclehome']['db']['version'] == '11.2.0.4' }
end
```

And then in the template I attempt to reference it as:

```
db_home=<% node.run_state['new_db_home'] %>
```

Comment: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57165863/1184717)

Comment: Thanks, @Mr., but to make sure I understand... are you suggesting I replace `node.run_state['new_db_home'] = db_home` with `node.default[:new_db_home] = db_home`? And if so, how exactly do I reference that in the template? `db_home=<% node['new_db_home'] %>`?

Comment: correct. just make sure that you read the node attribute only after you write the node attribute.